# How is NSLocaleCountryCode determined?

Tags: iphone

How is the NSLocaleCountryCode determined by the iPhone OS in versions greater than 3.0?

Can it be changed by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user can change their locale on the iPhone by going to Settings\General\International and choosing values for "Language" and "Region Format."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the locale depends on what language and region setting the user specifies.

Example:

Language: English
Region: United Kingdom
Locale: en_gb

Language: English
Region: United States
Locale: en_us